# How to create a IOUSBHostPipe::CompleteAsyncIO callback?

Tags: c++, macos-catalina, iokit, driverkit, macos-system-extension

I am writing a SystemExtension to communicate with a usb-device. My initial plan is to create a class `Transfer` that allocates the necessary [IOMemoryDescriptor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/driverkit/iomemorydescriptor?language=objc), and then pass the interface that I want the `Transfer` class to communicate with. I would like to have the [callback](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usbdriverkit/iousbhostpipe/3437961-completeasyncisochio?language=objc) resulting from [AsyncIO](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usbdriverkit/iousbhostpipe/3182647-asyncio?language=objc) completing to be made to the `Transfer` class. If I need to queue up multiple reads I could then create more instances of this class. In the callback `completeCallback` I would then unpack the data and then submit another [read](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usbdriverkit/iousbhostpipe/3182647-asyncio?language=objc).

I create the `Transfer` class with [`OSTypeAlloc(Transfer)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/driverkit/ostypealloc?language=objc).

The problem I am facing is that creating the OSAction fails with this stack trace:

```
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000010df950ce __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000010e07cf6a pthread_kill + 152
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000010df2c3a0 abort + 120
3   com.apple.DriverKit             0x000000010dc9124b __assert_rtn + 102
4   com.apple.DriverKit             0x000000010dc91a34 OSCopyOutObjects(IOUserServer_IVars*, IORPCMessageMach*, IORPCMessage*, bool) (.cold.4) + 35
5   com.apple.DriverKit             0x000000010dc7a2ff OSCopyOutObjects(IOUserServer_IVars*, IORPCMessageMach*, IORPCMessage*, bool) + 328
6   com.apple.DriverKit             0x000000010dc79126 InvokeRemote(IOUserServer_IVars*, unsigned long long, IORPC) + 159
7   com.apple.DriverKit             0x000000010dc796b6 OSMetaClassBase::Invoke(IORPC) + 754
8   com.apple.DriverKit             0x000000010dc90048 OSAction::Create_Call(OSObject*, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long, OSAction**) + 212
9   com.apple.DriverKit             0x000000010dc7ca15 OSAction::Create(OSObject*, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long, OSAction**) + 37
10  sc.example.MyUserUSBInterfaceDriver 0x000000010dc3bffc Transfer::CreateActioncompleteCallback(unsigned long, OSAction**) + 60 (Transfer.iig.cpp:175)
11  sc.example.MyUserUSBInterfaceDriver 0x000000010dc34e6e Transfer::setup(IOUSBHostInterface*, int, int) + 638 (Transfer.cpp:53)
```

If I instead move the callback to be defined, implemented and created in the class that is instantiated by the system when the usb-device is attached (this class is specified in the plist with key `IOUserClass`), then creating the [OSAction](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/driverkit/osaction?language=objc) object works fine.

The call to [`IOUSBHostInterface::Open`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usbdriverkit/iousbhostinterface/3182594-open?language=objc) is made from the `IOUserClass` passing a pointer to the `IOUserClass` as the first argument to `Open`. Should it be ok to do this? Or is it required that the `IOService` object is also the same object that receives the callbacks from `AsyncIO`.

```
class Transfer : public OSObject {
public:
  bool init() override;
  void free() override;

  bool setup(IOUSBHostInterface* interface, int endpointAddress, int maxPacketSize) LOCALONLY;
  bool submit() LOCALONLY;

protected:
   virtual void completeCallback(OSAction* action,
                        IOReturn status,
                        uint32_t actualByteCount,
                        uint64_t completionTimestamp) TYPE(IOUSBHostPipe::CompleteAsyncIO);
};
```

```
struct Transfer_IVars {
  IOUSBHostInterface* interface;
  int maxPacketSize;
  IOUSBHostPipe* pipe;
  IOBufferMemoryDescriptor* buffer;
  OSAction* ioCompleteCallback;
};

bool Transfer::init() {
  LOG_DEBUG();
  if (!super::init()) {
    LOG_ERROR("super::init failed");
  }

  if (ivars = IONewZero(Transfer_IVars, 1); ivars == nullptr) {
    LOG_ERROR("Allocating ivars failed");
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}

void Transfer::free() {
  LOG_DEBUG();
  IOSafeDeleteNULL(ivars, Transfer_IVars, 1);
  super::free();
}

bool Transfer::setup(IOUSBHostInterface* interface, int endpointAddress,
                     int maxPacketSize) {
  ivars->interface = interface;
  ivars->maxPacketSize = maxPacketSize;

  if (auto ret = interface->CopyPipe(endpointAddress, &ivars->pipe);
      ret != kIOReturnSuccess) {
    LOG_ERROR("Could not copy pipe: %{public}s, endpointAddress: %{public}d",
              kern_return_t_toCStr(ret), endpointAddress);
  }

  if (auto ret =
        interface->CreateIOBuffer(kIOMemoryDirectionIn, maxPacketSize, &ivars->buffer);
      ret != kIOReturnSuccess) {
    LOG_ERROR("CreateIOBuffer failed, ret: %{public}d", ret);
    return false;
  }

  if (auto ret = CreateActioncompleteCallback(0, &ivars->ioCompleteCallback);
      ret != kIOReturnSuccess) {
    LOG_ERROR("Failed to set iocomplete callback, ret: %{public}d", ret);
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

bool Transfer::submit() {
  if (auto ret = ivars->pipe->AsyncIO(ivars->buffer, ivars->maxPacketSize,
                                      ivars->ioCompleteCallback, 0);
      ret != kIOReturnSuccess) {
    LOG_ERROR("Failed to call AsyncIO, ret: %{public}d", ret);
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

void IMPL(Transfer, completeCallback) {
  LOG_DEBUG(
    "Complete callback bytecount %{public}d, timestamp: %{public}llu, status %{public}s",
    actualByteCount, completionTimestamp, kern_return_t_toCStr(status));
// TODO Unpack and then schedule another read.
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've probably found, this isn't documented anywhere. From my experimentation however, I get the impression that `OSAction` is basically a wrapper for IPC messages. If true, that would imply that the action's target object must have a representation in both the kernel and dext contexts, so that it makes sense for the kernel to send a message to it.

This doesn't appear to be the case for objects created with `OSTypeAlloc()`, as that just creates an object in the dext. It seems that only objects created using [`IOService::Create`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/driverkit/ioservice/3325579-create?language=objc) get representations in both contexts. This function only works for `IOService` subclasses though, which of course are rather heavyweight.

My recommendation would be to send your I/O completions through a completion method in your main driver object or your user client object, and in that completion method, forward the call to whatever actually originated the I/O. You can store arbitrary data in an `OSAction` by passing `sizeof(some_struct)` as the first argument to your `CreateAction…` call that creates it, and then get a pointer to that struct using

```
some_struct* my_context = static_cast<some_struct*>(action->GetReference());
```

You can put a regular function pointer and pointer to the ultimate target in there, or whatever you like really.

I don't believe the client object passed to the interface's or device's `Open()` function needs to be the same as the target for the `OSAction` used for the I/O callback. They both need to be kernel/dext shadowed objects, but they can be different objects.

Comment: I tried to send AsyncIO request to Interrupt endpoint, I have provided IOMemoryBufferDescriptor. Device has completed request with 16 bytes of data but unfortunately I am not able to see data in IOMemoryBufferDescriptor. By using above method i have stored ivars structure where I am storing GetRangeAddress IOMemoryBufferDescriptor.  do you have idea how to get interrupt packet data?

Comment: @david Please ask new questions as, well, a new question! I can’t really help you without seeing your code and comments are not a good place to post code. If you tag your question with the DriverKit tag, I will definitely see it and will attempt to answer it.